# Calling main method from another class

Tags: java

I have two java files or classes

One is a example called `URLConnectionReader.java` that does:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Second is `Tester.java` with:

```
public class Tester extends URLConnectionReader { 
   public static void main(String []args){

    URLConnectionReader.main(args);

    }  
}
```

All I wanted to do is execute, the main method in the `URLConnectionReader.java` in the Tester.java main method?

I get this error *"unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown"*

I plan to use the `Tester.java` as my main app and include various other methods or function.

What am I doing wrong here? It's frustrating as all the other examples are more complex code than this. I thought the "extend" will include the `URLConnectionReader.class` into the Tester.class no?

Comment: You need `public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {` in `Tester`.

Comment: Note that you almost certainly don't need to extends `URLConnectionReader` in your `Tester` class.

Comment: Thanks Andy, adding the "throws Exception"  in Tester.java worked (bloody syntax). But i wanted to asked why i dont need to extend? how does Tester.java know i am calling the URLConnectionReader main method without any references too it?? if you know what i mean. Unless the java takes in to consideration all the files in the directory at the time the program is executed??